# ActionMailer and ActiveModel

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, activemodel

I'm trying to make a simple contact us form so I need to implement the mailer.

I created a controller:

```
class ContactusController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @contact_us = Contactus.new
   end

   def new
      redirect_to(action: 'index')
   end

   def create
      @contact_us = Contactus.new(params[:contactus])
      if @contact_us.deliver
         flash[:notice] = "Thank-you, We will contact you shortly."
      else
         flash[:error] = "Oops!!! Something went wrong. Your mail was not sent."
      end
      render :index
    end
 end
```

As I don't want to save the data I used ActiveModel:

```
class Contactus
   extend ActiveModel::Naming
   include ActiveModel::Conversion
   include ActiveModel::Validations
   include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
   attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

   validate :name,
       :presence => true

   validates :email,
        :format => { :with => /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/ }

   validates :message,
        :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 1000 }

   def initialize(attributes = {})
      attributes.each do |name, value|
          send("#{name}=", value)
      end
   end

   def deliver
       return false unless valid?
   mail(
        :to => "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com",
        :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>),
        :reply_to => email,
        :subject => "Website inquiry",
        :body => message,
        :html_body => simple_format(message)
       )
   true
 end

 def persisted?
     false
 end
end
```

Everything works fine. The routing is good, the validation works, but the only error I get is: `undefined method mail for #<Contactus:0x007f9da67173e8>`

I tried to make mailer with name Contactus and user Model code in that, but I got 
the following error: `private method new used`

How can I use the ActionMailer function in ActiveModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be a bit more verbose of how to set up the mailer, run this command to generate your mailer:

```
rails generate mailer ContactMailer
```

add the following to a file named `app/mailers/contact_mailer`

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: #{from_email}

  def contact_mail(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail(to: #{email}, subject: #{Whatever your subject would be})
  end
end
```

ActionMailer uses views to render the layouts of its messages. I checked the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionMailer/Base/mail), but I couldn't find anything on the `html_body` option you're using here. Maybe try removing that and using `body: simple_format(message)` or just create the template `app/views/mailers/contact_mailer/contact_mail.html.erb` and put the message in yourself. You can see I made `@contact` an instance variable on purpose, so if I were to create such a template, I'd have access to all available attributes of the object, so you could customize a bit further if you wanted to.

*On a different note...*

I'm a little concerned that you're forwarding the `new` action to the `index` action here. Do you have a really good reason to be changing the RESTful approach? 9 times out of 10, when I've had strange problems with `private method called` or some other cryptic error, it's been when I was trying to cheat the system. If you reassign the `new` action to create the new `Contactus` object, does that fix your problem?

**Update for SMTP settings**

My employer's standard for these settings may not be the best out there, but here's what I've done so far. In my `environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :hash => 'of',
  :mail => 'client',
  :smtp => 'settings'
}
```

In my `environments/development.rb` I copy the same block, but replace the first line with

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

In my `environments/test.rb` I add none of the above. Instead, I add this line

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

but that's because I like to test that the emails get sent in my RSpec tests.

I'm not sure what your configs look like in your `environment.rb`, but you may want to make sure you're configuring through ActionMailer like this. Naturally, restart your app after making these changes and see if you still have authentication problems.

**For particular authentication problems**

My personal SMTP settings authenticate through gmail, so my settings in these files include the following pairs:

```
:address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
:port => #{port_number},
:domain => #{our_email_domain},
:authentication => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true
```

Try looking up your `port` and `domain`. A google search should suffice if you're not doing this for a business with its own domain. The `authentication` and `smarttls` settings should help if your password just isn't being interpreted correctly.

Comment: i'll try it for sure, about the new action problem i found that i was creating an object of mailer class but infact it have no construtor so there was the problem :)

Comment: now i'm a bit forward but now getting very strange errro   Net::SMTPAuthenticationError even though i entered right things in ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings in enviornment.rb any clue about that

Comment: Give me a couple minutes. I'll update my answer with some details.

Comment: i figure out the problem. i was using gmail and they need user to have  device specific password or domain specific i create a password for my mac and it work fine i recieve the mail. But getting error on production mode on heroku :( .  Where we have to put the smpt configuration in rails 4 in production.rb or enviornment.rb??

Comment: i figure that out it saysJul 06 11:45:14 weblabsolution app/web.1:  I, [2013-07-06T18:39:37.037813 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 425ms 
Jul 06 11:45:14 weblabsolution app/web.1:  F, [2013-07-06T18:39:37.042030 #2] FATAL -- :  
Jul 06 11:45:14 weblabsolution app/web.1:  Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password  but i'm entering right username and password

Comment: That might happen if you're not giving it right host or address that would recognize the username/password. Check my answer for an update soon.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [create a separate class](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) in `app/mailers` that inherits from `ActionMailer::Base`. In that class you can call the `mail` method. You cannot call `mail` directly in your `ContactUs` class.

Once you have setup your mailer class can use it like this in `ContactUs`:

```
ContactMailer.contact_mail(self).deliver
```

Comment: i used     ActionMailer::Base.mail(
      :to => "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>),
      :reply_to => email,
      :subject => "Website inquiry",
      :body => message,
      :html_body => simple_format(message)
    )   and it worked but not getting the mails though i'm getting success message, WHY SO??

Comment: can you be more precise what to do step wise.. sorry novice here :(